# how to configure the formatting of file upload in drupal 6

Tags: drupal, cck

When you use the file import in drupal 6 it adds a whole lot of formatting. How do I just get is to return the path. I am printing the following.

```
<?php
print $node->field_factsheet[0]['view']
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the path to the file use:

```
<?php
print $node->field_factsheet[0]['filepath']
?>
```

Comment: great thanks dan, Quick question, what other options do i have. Do you know where abouts in the api.drupal.org the properties are shown. Quite new to php.

Comment: Not sure offhand about api.drupal.org but if you use CCK + Content Templates you can get a list of variables when you create/edit templates for your content type.  Anyway, that's how I tracked this down.  Looks like you also have filename, filemime, filesize, timestamp available.